# Install helm chart automatically

Tags: beginner, go

I use the following code which works ok!

The code is installing helm charts in loop in k8s cluster, and I want to verify that I'm writing it ok.

```
tmpfile, err := ioutil.TempFile(kp, kcp)
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err, "error")
}

defer os.Remove(tmpfile.Name()) 

if _, err := tmpfile.Write(cfg); err != nil {
    return err
}
if err := tmpfile.Close(); err != nil {
    return err
}

kcfgFilePath := tmpfile.Name()
settings := cli.New()
ac := new(action.Configuration)
clientGetter := genericclioptions.NewConfigFlags(false)
clientGetter.KubeConfig = &kcfgFilePath



for _, chartInstallation := range charts {
    chart, err := loader.Load(chartInstallation.Path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    releaseName := releaseName + "-" + chartInstallation.Name
    if err := ac.Init(clientGetter, settings.Namespace(), os.Getenv("HELM_DRIVER"), func(format string, v ...interface{}) {
        
    }); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    releasePresent := true
    statusAction := action.NewStatus(ac)
    status, err := statusAction.Run(releaseName)
    if err != nil {
        if strings.Contains(err.Error(), driver.ErrReleaseNotFound.Error()) {
            releasePresent = false
        } else {
            return err
        }
    }

    if !releasePresent {
        // install chart
        installAction := action.NewInstall(ac)
        installAction.CreateNamespace = true
        installAction.Namespace = chartInstallation.Namespace
        installAction.ReleaseName = releaseName

        _, err := installAction.Run(chart, nil)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        log.Info("chart installed: ", "releaseName", releaseName)
    }

    if status != nil {
        if releasePresent && status.Info.Status.String() == release.StatusFailed.String() { 
            upgradeAction := action.NewUpgrade(ac)
            upgradeAction.Wait = true
            upgradeAction.ReuseValues = false
            upgradeAction.Recreate = false
            _, err := upgradeAction.Run(releaseName, chart, nil)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The error from `ioutil.TempFile` is unhandled, should also `return err` since everything after it won't work if the temporary file
  couldn't be created.
- The `strings.Contains` check is definitely the least preferred option
  to check for the kind of error.  If at all possible avoid it since
  it's actually fairly easy for that string to change with, say, a
  library upgrade without any notice, which would break the logic here.
- Same with `status.Info.Status.String() == release.StatusFailed` - are
  you sure it can't just be compared without the `String()` conversion?
- `tmpfile.Name()` is used twice, could already be moved to a variable.
- In fact, one of `tmpfile` and `kcfgFilePath` is redundant, I'd suggest
  directly assigning to `kcfgFilePath`.
- IMO `new` is obsolete and could very well be replaced by a regular
  variable declaration.
- `statusAction` could be inlined.

Actually it would be great if the imports were mentioned, that would
give readers a chance to find the actual signatures and such.  Without
that I'll leave it at those points.

Apart from these details it looks okay, though at some point you might
want to refactor things into smaller functions to bring a little order
into it.  Right now it's still a rather long block of code.  E.g. it
might be worth moving the inner part of the loop into a new function.
Or creating functions for each "action" that's currently only marked
with a comment, say `runInstall`, `runUpgrade`.  The temporary file bit
at the start could also very well be its own function (keeping the
`os.Remove` call at this level of course).

Edit: As requested to elaborate on the second point, it's better to do a
direct comparison of error values instead of string comparisons, since
they're just values too, this will be faster and not depend on string
values which might change in unexpected ways, like so:

```golang
// this is defined in the helm API
var ErrReleaseNotFound error = errors.New("release: not found")

// ...

// some time later, we get an error
{
    statusAction := action.NewStatus(ac)
    status, err := statusAction.Run(releaseName)
    if err != nil {
        if err == driver.ErrReleaseNotFound {
            releasePresent = false
        } else {
            return err
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

**But, actually**, we should all probably [start using
`errors.Is`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/errors/) so that even nested
errors would be correctly handled:

```golang
// ...
if errors.Is(err, ErrReleaseNotFound) {
    releasePresent = false
} else {
    return err
}
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, 1+ , one remark, could you please provide an example for the second option ?`strings.Contains` how its better to use it?

Comment: @bredstraruts added some, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks I learn a lot from you!

Comment: HI again , i've another question in that domain could you please have a look? thanks!https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259652/installing-charts-in-parallel-using-go